# Select previous element by it's class part string

Tags: jquery

I have the follwoing HTML:

```
<div id="divAreaId_1" class="SuppAreaParentDiv">
       <input type="hidden" value="3" class="hdnMaxSelection_1" id="hdnMaxSelection_1">

       <input type="checkbox" id="SuppItemId_2" class="chkSuppItem"> <br /> 
       <input type="checkbox" id="SuppItemId_3" class="chkSuppItem"> <br /> 
       <input type="checkbox" id="SuppItemId_4" class="chkSuppItem"> <br />
       <input type="checkbox" id="SuppItemId_5" class="chkSuppItem"> <br />
```

I am trying to get the 'input:hidden' value when any checkbox is checked! I need to do it by the 'input:hidden' partial class name:

```
$(".chkSuppItem").click(function () {
   var hdnMaxSelection = $(this).prev("[class*='hdnMaxSelection_']").val();
   alert(hdnMaxSelection); // I am getting here 'undefined'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**:

```
var hdnMaxSelection = $(this).siblings("[class*='hdnMaxSelection_']").val();
```

Currently, your selector only correct for the first checkbox since the hidden input is the immediately preceding sibling element of your first checkbox.

With `siblings()`, as long as your hidden input is the sibling of your checkboxes, then it'll work.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RsP8u/)**

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) in this context. Because [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) will only look for the immediate previous sibling with the provided constraint.

Try,

```
$(".chkSuppItem").click(function () {
   var hdnMaxSelection = $(this).siblings("[class*='hdnMaxSelection_']").val();
   alert(hdnMaxSelection); 
});
```

Or you can try with [.prevAll(selector)](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/),

```
$(".chkSuppItem").click(function () {
   var hdnMaxSelection = $(this).prevAll("[class*='hdnMaxSelection_']").first().val();
   alert(hdnMaxSelection); 
});
```

**[DEMO for .prevAall()](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/RsP8u/1/)**